# Find a string with parenthesis inside another string

Tags: android, string

I am working on android application and want to convert all the typed text smileys to emoticons.

I have prepared a Hashmap to list all the text smileys with their Emoticon's Unicode.

`

```
public static final HashMap<String, Integer> smileysMap = new HashMap<>();

// To add :) :-) :) :] =)
smileysMap.put(":-\\)", 0x1f60a);
smileysMap.put(":\\)", 0x1f60a);
smileysMap.put(":\\]", 0x1f60a);
smileysMap.put("=\\)", 0x1f60a)
String statusBody = "Hello World :)";

Set<String> set = smileysMap.keySet();
for (String s1 : set) {
      if(statusBody.contains(s1)){
           statusBody = statusBody.replaceAll(s1,smileysMap.get(s1));
      }
}
```

`

But the condition `if(statusBody.contains(s1))`always get fail. Then how can I check it out.

Please help me if anyone know how to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i modified your code and its working fine

```
public static final HashMap<String, Integer> smileysMap = new HashMap<>();

// To add :) :-) :) :] =)
smileysMap.put(":-)", 0x1f60a);
smileysMap.put(":)", 0x1f60a);
smileysMap.put(":]", 0x1f60a);
smileysMap.put("=)", 0x1f60a)
String statusBody = "Hello World :)";

Set<String> set = smileysMap.keySet();
for (String s1 : set) {
      if(statusBody.contains(s1)){

            statusBody = statusBody.replace(s1,"any string");              
           /*replaceAll function will give you PatternSyntaxException: Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern near index 2: :) so i used replace function instead*/

      }
}
```

and you will get error for this line also  **statusBody = statusBody.replaceAll(s1,smileysMap.get(s1));** 
As replace and replace method accepts 2 string arguments

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

> But the condition `if(statusBody.contains(s1))` always get fail

Of course! In the map, you have these as keys:

- ":-\)"
- ":\)"
- ":\]"
- "=\)"

If you turn these into verbatim strings,

- ":-)"
- ":)"
- ":]"
- "=)"

So far so good. Now let's see whether your `statusBody` contains any of these. Your `statusBody`:

```
"Hello World :)"
```

Does it contain ":-)"? Or ":)"? Or ":]"? Or "=)"?

None of these!

See?

I think you did not add the correct stuff into the map. I think you mean:

- ":-)"
- ":)"
- ":]"
- "=)"

So just change the `put` methods' arguments and PROBLEM SOLVED!

I just found out another problem in your code. `replaceAll` takes two string arguments, but you are giving it a string and an int. You should convert the int to string first!

Comment: I can not add :) as it is in the map as it gives me the below error 
`Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern near index 2: :)`

Comment: You must be using some regex there. But you did not show it in your code. If you don't need regex to parse the stuff, don't do it, remove the regex code. If you _really_ need that piece of code, I suggest that you call `replaceAll` when you check the strings. Replace all the \ with empty strings. @PrithnirajNicyone